# Creating a front end SELECT query builder /search

Tags: c#, .net, search, azure-sql-database

I've been searching around for a good tool for .NET to help building and running semi-complex `queries` against my `SQL Azure Database`.

I'm looking for something similar to this:

http://hotelmagician.com/hotels/

Essentially, there is very limited "text" search (perhaps only city name), so I don't want an engine that simple does a full text search on my DB.

I want users to be able to define a search from my database of employees with dropdowns and check boxes.

So a search might look something like, imagine that these are series of dropdown:

```
 State:  IL
 IsTerminated: false
 RecordCreatedBefore: 10/10/2012
 HasPhoneNumber: true
```

Is there anything out there that will help make this process easier, or do we have to build the engine ourselves?

If it matters, we are using `NHibernate`. I've looked into `Lucence`, but that seems to be far more of a "full text" type search than the results builder I am looking for.

**Edit:**  We have about 100 searchable fields on each "Employee" we are trying to search.